# Vivado partial reconfiguration error

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, vivado, configuration

I am trying to implement a minimal partial reconfiguration project using the Vivado GUI. I have successfully enabled the project for reconfiguration and created a partition definition. The problem lies when I try to add a second reconfigurable module using the partial reconfiguration wizard.

After adding the second reconfigurable module and setting up the config and design runs to include this new reconfigurable module, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: [Vivado 12-172] File or Directory '1/PR_Testing/PR_Testing.srcs/sources_1/new/Pr_Unit_3.vhd' does not exist

I know for a fact that the file does exist as I just created and simulated it.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this may be, and how it could possibly be fixed? The command executed by Vivado from the Journal file is:

`add_files -norecurse {C:/MEng_Project/Dev/Phase 1/PR_Testing/PR_Testing.srcs/sources_1/new/Pr_Unit_3.vhd}  -of_objects [get_reconfig_modules pru3]`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is (partially):

```
C:/MEng_Project/Dev/Phase 1/PR_Testing
                         ^
```

Note the SPACE between "Phase" and "1".  I believe this is your problem.

Please try renaming your folder to **not** have a space.

Comment: Perfect, works now thank you! I remember my professor complaining about not being allowed spaces in the file path along time ago but it never occurred to me :)

Comment: @TomHudson If you're insistent on the space, you could escape it. Better is to just never have spaces in directory or file names, though.

Comment: Or if you just want to abuse yourself you can use the DOS short file name which is probably Phas1~1.  But to be sure you need to list it with "DIR /X".  So your path might become: C:/MEng_Project/Dev/Phas1~1/PR_Testing.  But I don't like playing these games unless absolutely necessary.